# React, Material-UI, DataGrid, renderCell | Prevent renderCell event from firing when I focus

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

Whenever I focus or unfocus the IP cell the renderCell event is fired, I need to prevent this so that the logic programmed in the renderCell doesn't get re-executed.

```
    // ip
    {
      field: "ip",
      headerName: "IP".toUpperCase(),
      renderCell: (params) => {
        console.log("renderCell executed => ");
        return params.value;
      }
    },
```

Here is the example ([CodeSandbox.io link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rendercell-26txy2?file=/src/App.js)), the column is IP, you have to look at the console logs so that you see that the renderCell is being executed again every time the focus is done or the focus is stopped, you can try it by clicking on the previous cell and moving with the arrow to the right.

I need to prevent the logic programmed in the renderCell doesn't get re-executed when focus or unfocus cell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.